# Determine splitting field of $X^4 + 2X^2+4$ over $\mathbb Q$ and its degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The full question is:

1. What is the minimal polynomial $f$ of $i\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}$ over $\mathbb Q$?
2. What is the splitting field $E$ of $f$ over $\mathbb Q$ and what is $[E:\mathbb Q]$, the degree of the splitting field?

I have found $f$ to be $X^4 + 2X^2+4$ and $E$ to be $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}},i\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}})$, but I am unable to find $[E:\mathbb Q]$. I know that $[E:\mathbb Q]=[E: \mathbb Q(i\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}})][\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}):\mathbb Q]$ and $[\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}):\mathbb Q]=4$.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $X^4 + 2X^2 + 4$ is irreducible and has 4 roots: $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$. Let's define

- $\alpha_1 = i\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}$
- $\alpha_2 = i\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1 - i \sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \alpha_1$.
- $\alpha_3 = -i\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}} = -\alpha_1$
- $\alpha_4 = -i\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}} = -\alpha_2$

The splitting field is $L = \mathbb Q(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4) = \mathbb Q(\alpha_1, i \sqrt{3})$.

Now $\alpha_1^2 = -1(1+i\sqrt{3})$. We can see $L$ as a quadratic field extension of an intermediate field $M = \mathbb Q(i \sqrt{3})$. In that case $L/M$ occurs by extending with the polynomial $X^2 + 1 + i \sqrt{3}$.

Therefore $[L:\mathbb Q] = [L:M][M:\mathbb Q] = 4$.

Comment: I don't think $\alpha_2= \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \alpha_1$. Is it possible you have made a typo there?